Unable to acces to the translation section in prestashop
When I access the translation section I get the error in the figure.
Attempted to load class "ThemeCollection" from namespace "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Addon\Theme". Did you forget a "use" statement for "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\MailTemplate\ThemeCollection"?
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException 0]
I use the warehouse theme. I tried to disable the theme but did not get any results.

Please share more details, like the code involved
